# How to avoid Snakemake rule from using incomplete output file from other rules

Tags: snakemake

```
rule rule1:
    output: tsv = "..."
    input: faa = "..."
    shell:
        """
        awk ... > {output.tsv}
        some commands {input.faa} | awk ... >> {output.tsv}
        """
rule rule2:
    output:
        tsv = "..."
    input:
        tsv = rules.rule1.output.tsv,
    shell:
        """
        awk ... {input.tsv} > {output.tsv}
        """
```

As it illustrated above, rule2 takes input file from rule1.
According to the official docs, since the output file in rule1 is created successfully by awk, Snakemake assumes everything worked fine, even if my output file is incomplete, because awk is going to append to that file. Snakemake just ran rule2 and took the incomplete file from rule1. Actually, the second awk command in rule1 have not being executed, leaving the output file incomplete.

Comment: *the second awk command in rule1 have not being executed* I doubt this is the case. snakemake will execute every command in the shell block and each command has to have exit code 0 for rule2 to be executed next. If any command fails, the incomplete output will be deleted and the pipeline will stop with error. Could it be that `input.faa` is empty so it seems as if the second `awk` has not been executed? Add more detail to your question if this doesn't help, e.g. add the actual awk commands.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the code sample above to  ```some commands {input.faa} | awk ... >> {output.tsv}``` because previous one was incorrect. It should be a command pipeline and awk takes input from previous pipeline output. I figured out that the output of previous command is empty ( nothing is piped to awk). Therefore the seconda awk "seemed like" not being executed.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, Snakemake detecting the presence of `output.csv` and assuming the rule completed successfully (since your `awk`s didn't error) is working as intended.

It's not very easy for me to suggest specific edits since the commands are not complete, but how about creating intermediate files in your rule for the two `awk` commands, then combining them, so that if one or the other don't run the rule fails. Something like:

```
rule rule1:
    output: tsv = "...", int1 = temp(".../{sample}_i1.tsv"), int2 = temp(".../{sample}_i2.tsv")
    input: faa = "..."
    shell:
        """
        awk ... > {output.int1}
        awk ... {input.faa} >> {output.int2}
        [some logic to make sure the processing is complete]
        cp {output.int2} {output.tsv}
        """
```

I wrapped both intermediates in `temp()` so that snakemake cleans them up after the rule ends.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll try the ```temp()``` method next time